# How do I extend the duration of each photo in a fading slideshow carousel?

Tags: javascript

I've managed to manipulate a slideshow carousel from W3Schools for a carousel slideshow with fading. However, it is unclear to me how to make each photo stay on for longer—to pause longer before fading to the next image (that is, 30 seconds to several minutes).
How do I extend and hold each photo longer on the screen?

(The intent is to only use this on Chrome as a photo display for my monitor/tv)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; background-color: black; height: 100vh;">
        <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="object-fit: contain; max-width: 100%; position: center center;">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_01.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myIndex = 0;
        carousel();

        function carousel() {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            myIndex++;
            if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
            x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed I can't just set the timeout longer (that is, 90000 instead of 9000) as that causes some photos to just repeat. I also tried to adjust the CSS to make it longer than 10 seconds, but that also causes other weird artifacts/clipping.

Here is a test [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle). I tried replacing the setTimeout with setInterval and increasing the interval to 90000 and it still just repeats the first photo, instead of making the photo display longer:

https://jsfiddle.net/mznek2fv/

Comment: If you want to pause longer just increase the settimeout value, if your photos clip or repeat it can't be related with that, it must be another problem.

Comment: I set it to 90000 from 9000 and the first photo still displays for the same length of time - the same photo just repeats instead of moving on to the next photo.

Comment: I suspect the setTimeout is more of a total time of fade-in-display-fade-out, and not the actual time it stays on full image display.

Comment: Usually `setInterval` is more appropriate for this type of usecase, because you want a carousel to loop indefinitely (until you revoke the loop).